# Simplest way to share dynamic content to Facebook news feed with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, share, facebook-like

I want my users to be able to share dynamic content on their Facebook news feed. There's no other Facebook integration (e.g. Facebook login or other server-side integration) so I want this to be as light as possible.

This is where I got, but how does it looks like? It seems to work, but I'm not sure if I've thought of everything.

```
<button id="fb-publish">Share to Facebook</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: MY_FACEBOOK_APP_ID, cookie: true, status: true, xfbml: true, oauth: true
    });
    var fbAuth = null;
    var fbShare = function() {
        FB.ui({
            method: "feed",
            display: "iframe",
            link: "http://example.com/",
            caption: "Example.com",
            description: "Here is the text I want to share.",
            picture: "http://example.com/image.png"
        });
    };
    $("#fb-publish").click(function() {
        if (!fbAuth) {
            FB.login(function(response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    fbAuth = response.authResponse;
                    fbShare();
                }
            }, {scope: 'publish_stream'});
        } else {
            fbShare();
        }
    });
})();
</script>
```

Also, if I want to attach an image from a URL (bigger than just the 50x50 pixel image defined in the `picture` field), how can I do that with just JavaScript? Or can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to leave out `authResponse` caching and call `FB.login()` every time. It briefly opens a popup window, but at least there's no case where user has logged out in another tab or window and the cached `authResponse` has gone stale. The briefly flashing popup window is not that big of an issue, since I don't think users will share the same page multiple times, anyway.

Here's my final code which is even simpler than the original one:

```
<button id="fb-publish">Share to Facebook</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: MY_FACEBOOK_APP_ID, cookie: true, status: true, xfbml: true, oauth: true
    });
    var fbShare = function() {
        FB.ui({
            method: "feed",
            display: "iframe",
            link: "http://example.com/",
            caption: "Example.com",
            description: "Here is the text I want to share.",
            picture: "http://example.com/image.png"
        });
    };
    $("#fb-publish").click(function() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                fbShare();
           }
        }, {scope: 'publish_stream'});
    });
})();
</script>
```

And as mentioned by Tolga Arican, if it's ok to you that the sharing dialog opens in a popup window, you don't even need to call `FB.login()` and ask for the `publish_stream` permission; just call `FB.ui({ method: "feed" })` directly and you're good to go:

```
<button id="fb-publish">Share to Facebook</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: MY_FACEBOOK_APP_ID, cookie: true, status: true, xfbml: true, oauth: true
    });
    $("#fb-publish").click(function() {
        FB.ui({
            method: "feed",
            link: "http://example.com/",
            caption: "Example.com",
            description: "Here is the text I want to share.",
            picture: "http://example.com/image.png"
        });
    });
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure appId defined.

2) In FB.login , response.authResponse may not work. I'm not pretty sure but just throw console.log, it may response.session

3) in method:feed , you can put larger images for picture, but it wil downsize. There is no way to put big images as a feed thumbnail. It is just a thumb of a feed..

For the lightest method:feed js, you don't need display:iframe i guess.

```
FB.ui( {
method: 'feed',
name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
link: 'http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
caption: 'Reference Documentation',
description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.' }, function(response) {} });
```

Comment: Without `display:iframe` the dialog opens in a popup window which doesn't look nice. What do you mean with `response.authResponse` not working? About the image thing: there is the `attachment` field, but it isn't really different from the `picture` field, right? What I was referring to was to actually upload a full size image without resizing.

Comment: about response.authResponse, once i figured out it has been changed and new type of it is session. Just to be clear, try console.log(response) on firefox firebug or chrome js console.

Comment: for the attaching a picture on a wall post , try to add this one: attachment: {  media: [{  type: "image", src: 'http://...test.png',
 href: "http://www....com/"  }], name: "Attachment Name", caption: 'Attachment Caption', href: "http://www....com/" },